# Can i still use expo after i detach my react native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to use expokit and also other native library, how can i do this?

Do i need to start my app using **create-react-native-app** and then detach it or can i start from **react-native init** app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create an app with **create-react-native-app** and then **detach** you can still use most of Expo's feature such as maps for instance.

But if you create a react native project with **react-native init** you won't be able to use any of expo's feature.

I started my first project with **create-react-native-app** but then quickly realized most libraries weren't supported by expo yet and required you to detached. After I detached tho I got into a lot of bugs when trying to link new libraries so I finally decided to make a new app from scratch with **react-native init** and import all my components.

I know this is a late answer by for anyone else trying to get a better understanding of this topic, I decided to write an answer and share my experience with you.

Comment: Upvote, I cannot think of any reason to use`expo` at all other than being able to run react native apps on an iOS device when using windows operating system to develop. Any module that requires `react-native link` is not supported by `expo`, and there are a lot of them

Comment: but we unable using expo push notifications

Comment: @msmaromi I would recommend using react-native-onesignal for push notification, once you mange to set it up properly it is by far the most reliable library to my opinion.